# R - remove last row and convert row in column in dataframes within a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe, row, col

I need your help as I have to:

- remove the last row in all my dataframes contained in a list
  and
- add a new column to all the dataframes which contains the first row value of them.

Here an example of one of my dataframes:

```
         V1        V2        V3
2         7002                    
8  14 Feb 1959    47.664     1.310
9  25 Aug 1960   680.615     3.790
10 08 Aug 1961   287.893     2.490
11 11 Feb 1962   405.366     2.920
12 14 Dec 1962   312.010     2.560
13 18 Aug 1964   167.684     1.930

    [....]

53 19 Jan 2004   385.980     2.835
54 13 Jun 2005   415.942     2.939
55 26 Nov 2005   280.773     2.431
56       [END]
```

So, in this case, add 7002 as new column and remove the 56th row. 
I have got ~290 dataframes in my list.

Thanks
Paolo

Comment: Are those values in 'V2' and 'V3' blanks for the first row in each list element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `lapply` to loop over the `list`, remove the last row (`x[-nrow(x),]`), and create a new column with the first cell value.

```
lst1 <- lapply(lst, function(x) transform(x[-nrow(x),], NewCol = x[1,1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

If all your dataframes look the same you could use something similar to that:

```
df1 <- data.frame(matrix(data =  (rnorm(9)), 3, 3))
df2 <- data.frame(matrix(data =  (100:108), 3, 3))
colnames(df1) <- c("V1", "v2", "V3")
colnames(df2) <- c("V1", "v2", "V3")

list1 <- list(df1, df2)
list2 <- list1

for(i in 1:length(list2)) {
  list2[[i]] <- list2[[i]][-length(list2[[i]]), ]
  colnumber <- dim(list2[[i]])[2] + 1
  list2[[i]]$V4 <- list2[[i]][1, 1]
}

list2
```

However, if you have a more complicated structure or the values are not in the same spot in every dataframe, you will have to look for a dplyr or apply-solution or even write your own function for doing so.

I hope it helps.